# What is this switch called?

Tags: switches, identification

Whats the correct name for this switch? It is 12 mm high measured from the PCB with a 6.5 mm base. It is flexible in that it can move around in the switch base.

The switch is used on an instrument panel on a motorcycle to adjust the clock. This switch is stuck, stopping me from changing the time.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can get it anything more specific than 'push button' or 'tactile switch', but I might be wrong. Or is that what you're looking for? -- by the way, _in which direction_ is it flexible?

Comment: It looks like SW1 - according to the artwork on the PCB. It's just a button but functionally it might be a reset switch for a microprocessor, an interlock switch, part of a simple keyboard (think up-down, left-right control).

Comment: I buy such switches (but not realy flexible!) in bulk from Electronics China, I think I could specify any height I want. The general term is 'tactile switch' or 'tact switch', but that can refer to many many variants.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a little tactile switch in the common [Omron B3F](http://www.omron.com/ecb/products/sw/21/b3f.html) form factor. They have various options for actuator height, actuating force, colour and, as you note, type of material for the mechanical "top".

Specifically, yours looks like a [B3F-1070](http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/B3F-1070/SW406-ND/38362).

Comment: Thanks for all your input, I just wasn't sure of the correct name for this switch, which made it difficult to search for. Now that I know that's a tactile switch, my life has become so much easier. Congrats on such a great and helpful community. Keep up the good work.